# Minibuffer function bindings

Tags: key-bindings, minibuffer

Many times, i use commands like `M-x what-face` to get the font face for character under cursor, (or) `M-x find-function-on-key` to get the key bindings for a key sequence. These functions work on the main frame/buffer.

But, how to get the properties for minibuffer's face font (or) may be, key bindings for key inputs (or) `copy-region` on minibuffer itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For key bindings in minibuffer keymaps:

Load library [`help-fns+.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/help-fns%2b.el) and use **`C-h M-k`** (command `describe-keymap`). See [**Help Plus**](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/HelpPlus).

For faces and other information, you might need to consult the code that implements/uses them. But for faces you might make progress by using `M-x list-faces-display` (or even `M-x customize-face` followed by the input `minibuf TAB`).

Comment: does `describe-keymap` take a string input, if yes do i need to escape it. in `keymap:` prompt in minibuffer, i entered `C-1` and it said `[No Match]`

Comment: `describe-keymap` takes the name of a keymap **variable**, that is, a variable whose value is a keymap. Completion is available for this name.  (`C-h f describe-keymap` tells you this.)  So you need to know the names of the variables whose values are minibuffer keymaps.  All you need to know is that their names all start with `minibuffer-` - so just type `minib TAB` and completion will show you all of their names.